# How to open url with change list by custom tools in perforce P4

Tags: cmd, perforce, custom-tools

I want to open URL with selected changelist via Tools > Manage Custom Tools > New

```
Application: cmd.exe
Arguments: /c start https://myserver.org?query=%c^&param=value
```

It does not replace %c with Changelist Number and cuts the url after query=. I have suspicion that it can't replace %c inside of a string. If I put #CL instead of %c it is opened correctly.

I have working solution using a python script

```
import webbrowser
import sys

webbrowser.open("https://myurl.org?query={0}&param=value".format(sys.argv[1]))
```

And a P4 custom tool

```
Application: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\python.exe
Arguments" d:\openurl.py %c
```

I'm wondering how to do it without having a python as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using explorer instead of cmd

```
  Application: explorer.exe
  Arguments: "https://myserver.org?param=value&query=%c"
```